# Show Minutes as Intervals on the horizontal scale in TradingView Lightweight

Tags: ios, swift, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

is it possible to show minutes instead of a day in the lightweight chart? in swift the CandlestickData accepts time in timestamps, however it only displays the day

thank you

the CandlestickData accepts time in timestamps, however it only displays the day

Answer (score 2):

Lightweight charts will show a bar for every data point that you supply, it doesn't matter if it is at a day resolution (interval) or at a minute interval or anything else.

If you give it 100 bars then it will show 100 bars.

With regards to the time scale. You can set options to change how the timestamp is displayed. See the options here: https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/TimeScaleOptions

You are probably interested in this property:
https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/TimeScaleOptions#timevisible

you can set this options within the createChart options or via the applyOptions api method. Similar guide here: https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/tutorials/customization/chart-colors#applying-options